Solving PDE on domain bounded by two intersecting curves (parabolas) and conformal mapping
I am trying to solve a PDE similar to the heat equation:
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} + (\vec{u} \cdot \nabla)T = D \Delta T
$$
(where $\vec{u}$ is a known advecting vector field) with some boundary conditions on a domain bounded by two intersecting curves $h(x)$ and $b(x)$ (for example parabolas):

I also know that $h(x) = a b(x) + c$, with $a$ and $c$ real constants.
I'm looking to find a mapping of this domain to a simpler one, on which I could properly define a grid, either a rectangle or maybe a circle.
I am completely new to conformal mapping, and I've been doing some literature. However, I think I lack the proper keywords or may not exactly know what I am looking for.
Hence, I'm looking for any advice on solving this PDE on this domain, including pointing towards the proper transforms.
